# strange characters appear in html file when inlcuding a php file

Tags: php, html

vars.php

```
<?php 
   $sometext="text";
?>
```

index.php

```
     <?php 
include ('file1.php');
include ('variables.php');
 function genStr() {
    $len = 5;
    $base='ABCDEFGHKLMNOPQRSTWXYZ123456789';
    $max=strlen($base)-1;
    $str='';
    mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
    while (strlen($str)<$len+1) {
     $str.=$base{mt_rand(0,$max)};
    }   
    return $str;
 }


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//processing
}?>
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
           "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>title</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="title" content="title" /> 
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Now when I check the index.php page  with firebug everything from within  tags is moved into  and there are some **white characters** added, so there is a rectangle on the top of the page in the browser. When I delete these few invisible characters in firebug, the rectangle dissappears

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
  <head></head> 
 <body>
   "  " <!-- white spaces here -->
<title>title</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta name="title" content=title" /> 
<body>
```

Comment: Do you get the same mangled HTML when you use the regular view-source option (ctrl-U in FF)?

Comment: What does a hexedit of your vars.php show? You wouldn't be the first to have invisible ones in there...

Comment: Well there aren't any such. But, I had some functions in vars.php. And when I moved these functions to index.php the problem didn't happen.

Comment: There's some weird copy and pasting going on here. There's no way that the `index.php` that you supplied results in the HTML that you posted. In particular, the `<title>` and `<meta>` tags are in the wrong place. Can you provide a URL for us, instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the text editor I used (notepad++). When I opened and saved the file in PsPad those characters dissappeared..

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `"` here:

```
<meta name="title" content=title" />
```

should be:

```
<meta name="title" content="title" />
```

**Edit:** the only way I can reproduce that, is by outputting anything other than spaces and new-lines before the `doctype`. Is php working when you `echo` for example something in de body of the page?

Answer (score 1):

try changing your index.php to:

```
<?php include ('vars.php');?><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>...
```

It should remove that extra line on top

Comment: didn't help it. I even checked encodings of the files.

Comment: thats odd. u sure u posted all ur php there?

Comment: try deleting the white characters inf Firebug, or Chrome webdev. The rectangle on the top will dissappear

Comment: i see that, but look at view-source:http://oravaman.lietadla.com/test.php in chrome. the source looks correct

Comment: try looking at the developer-tools source in chrome. Everything that is supposed to be inside <head> is inside <body>

Comment: help ends here. i said i saw that. u did **NOT** post all of your code in ur question, so i cannot help

Comment: i just didn't want to be too detailed, that usually discourages people

Comment: and there is ur issue. right in the index.php. all the space before the 1st `<?php` unless that was a typo

Comment: and what is done in those includes? did u make sure nothing gets echoed or printed?

Comment: OK thank you for your help, I'll just remove them includes.
Have a good day.

Comment: no, nothing does.
In file1.php there are just some variables and file2.php contains a function for sending a mail.